# Find root node for all nodes in a neo4j cypher query

Tags: database, database-design, neo4j, cypher

I am organizing a database of company merger and acquisition information, and for any acquired company in the database I need to find its current company. Basically, I need to find the root node of every node.

I've been playing around with using a Neo4j database for this, since I think a graph-based DB might be a good option. My structure looks like this (forgive the lack of proper syntax, this is just for clarity):

```
(Company)-[Acquired]->(Company)-[Acquired]->(Company)...etc.
```

This could be a single level, e.g. a single company acquired one other company and that was the end of things, or there could be multiple layers, where one company acquired another company who then acquired another company and so on.

What I need to do is list each company in the database (it's only about 500 for now) and its current company owner.

My Cypher query skills are pretty poor at the moment, although I know some SQL and other languages (Java, Python), and I'm having trouble finding a comprehensive guide to the query language online, so I really don't know where to start for this one. Any help would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. If you have a better idea for which DB should be used for this sort of thing, or a better database design, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's put together a sample dataset:

```
CREATE (c1:Company {id:1}),
       (c2:Company {id:2}),
       (c3:Company {id:3}),
       (c4:Company {id:4}),
       (c5:Company {id:5}),
       (c6:Company {id:6}),
       (c7:Company {id:7}),
       (c8:Company {id:8}),
       (c9:Company {id:9}),
       (c10:Company {id:10}),

       (c2)-[:ACQUIRED]->(c3),
       (c4)-[:ACQUIRED]->(c5)-[:ACQUIRED]->(c6),
       (c7)-[:ACQUIRED]->(c8)-[:ACQUIRED]->(c9),
       (c8)-[:ACQUIRED]->(c10)
```

[image]

This allows us to test a few different scenarios:

- A company hasn't acquired another company (id 1)
- There is a length = 1 path of acquires (ids 2,3)
- There is a length > 1 path of acquires (ids 4,5,6)
- There are branched acquires (ids 7,8,9,10)

Then you can get a list of companies and their owner like so:

```
MATCH ownership = shortestPath((owner:Company)-[:ACQUIRED*0..]->(acquired:Company))
WHERE NOT ()-[:ACQUIRED]->(owner)
RETURN acquired.id AS company, head(nodes(ownership)).id AS owner;

╒═══════╤═════╕
│company│owner│
╞═══════╪═════╡
│1      │1    │
├───────┼─────┤
│2      │2    │
├───────┼─────┤
│3      │2    │
├───────┼─────┤
│4      │4    │
├───────┼─────┤
│5      │4    │
├───────┼─────┤
│6      │4    │
├───────┼─────┤
│7      │7    │
├───────┼─────┤
│8      │7    │
├───────┼─────┤
│9      │7    │
├───────┼─────┤
│10     │7    │
└───────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and great example! Unfortunately, that query is not working for me. It's just returning the company's name itself, not its owner's. I'm replacing `id` with `company` since "company" holds the names in my DB. But other than that, are there other changes I should be making to that code to tailor it to my specific DB? Thanks again!

Comment: If you can give me a sample of your dataset we can figure out the correct property to use.

Comment: @NickBurleigh is it possible you're using the wrong relationship type? Make sure to edit the query to use the correct relationship type. It is case sensitive.